# I can't figure out the indexing error in my code to find the minimum value in a list

Tags: python, indexing

I've just started coding and have been setting myself small challenges. My latest was a function to calculate the smallest item in a list, but it throws up the error 'IndexError: list index out of range' for the line 'if mylist[leftcomparitor] < mylist[rightcomparitor]:'. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help much appreciated :-)

```
mylist = [45,46,8,2,4,7,2,4,67,46,2] #Make this user input later
def findthemin():
    leftcomparitor = 0
    rightcomparitor = 1
    minimumvalue = mylist[leftcomparitor]
    while rightcomparitor <= len(mylist):
        if mylist[leftcomparitor] < mylist[rightcomparitor]:
            minimumvalue = mylist[leftcomparitor]
            leftcomparitor += 1
            rightcomparitor += 1
        else:
            leftcomparitor += 1
            rightcomparitor += 1
    print("The minimum value is " + str(minimumvalue))
findthemin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your code modified by me. I signed the changed lines with # changed here.   The problem was about len(list) that in Python list start at index 0. Moreover I had to modify the way you were comparing left and right-comparator. I am learning python too so I am sorry about not being able to be more explicative. Don’t forget to run tests on your algorithm so to be sure they are working the way you expect.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

mylist = [45,46,8,2,7,2,67,46,35,7,3,99] #Make this user input later
def findthemin(mylist):
    leftcomparitor = 0
    rightcomparitor = 1
    minimumvalue = mylist[leftcomparitor]
    while rightcomparitor <= len(mylist)-1:  #changed here 
        if mylist[leftcomparitor] <= mylist[rightcomparitor]:
            minimumvalue = mylist[leftcomparitor]
#            leftcomparitor += 1
            rightcomparitor += 1
        else:
            leftcomparitor = rightcomparitor    #changed here
            rightcomparitor += 1
    print("The minimum value is " + str(minimumvalue), ' for a len ' ,len(mylist), ' list ')


findthemin(mylist)
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple virtually identical answers to the same question, or to multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this approach:

```
int min = list[0];

for(int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {

    if(list[i] < min) {
      min = list[i];
    }
}

System.out.println("Minimum value is: " + min);
```

Basically, what I have done is assert the first value in the list to a variable called `min`, then execute a for loop starting from the next position, which is `1` and compare all the values with the most recent `min` value and if that value is less than my `min` value, assign that value to the `min` variable and it will repeat that all the way to the end of the list. Let me know if this works.

Note that my code is written in Java, you can change to whatever you like, but it's kinda the same.

Comment: You welcome, I think this is one of the cleaner ways to find the min value in a list. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, this has worked :-) You helped me realise that there was a far bigger problem with my code than the indexing issue, I've put my updated code as an answer. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting an `IndexError` is this: `len`  returns the number of elements in a list, but accessing an array via an index is usually **0-based**.

In case your list consists of 1 element, `len(mylist)` returns 1, but in order to access the first element, you have to call `mylist[0]`!

so just change
`while rightcomparitor <= len(mylist)`
to
`while rightcomparitor < len(mylist)`
and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There have been several helpful posts so I thought I would update with my improved code so that other people can learn from it as well.

My original post identified an error with the indexing. I had mistakenly thought the index position of the final element was 11, but it is 10, because we start from 0. A quick '-1' fixes that.

But there was a bigger error with the code that meant it wouldn't find the smallest value. I had set it up so that I was comparing each sequential pair of values and trying to find the smallest in each sequential pair, rather than comparing each value with the minimum value up to that point. I didn't need the 'leftcomparitor' value at all.

Finally, I should have also clarified that I was intentionally looking for a lengthy, manual route to identifying the min value, rather than making use of in-built functions.

My fixed code is:

```
mylist = [45,46,8,2,4,7,2,4,67,46,2] #Make this user input later
def findthemin():
    rightcomparitor = 1
    minimumvalue = mylist[0]
    while rightcomparitor <= len(mylist)-1:
        if minimumvalue > mylist[rightcomparitor]:
            minimumvalue = mylist[rightcomparitor]
            rightcomparitor += 1
        else
            rightcomparitor += 1
    print("The minimum value is " + str(minimumvalue))
findthemin()
```

Thanks to all for their help.

Luke

Comment: Or, perhaps better, `while rightcomparitor < len(mylist):`

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try this approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

mylist = [45,46,8,2,7,2,67,46,35,7,3,99,777,888] #Make this user input later

print("The minimum value is ",min(mylist))
```

It makes use of python built-in  min() function:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Comment: And I assure you, there's no need to date and sign your code here (or anywhere). Here, your account is attached to each contribution. And in a real development situation, use version control software instead.

Comment: Mavro did the same not answering the op question but proposing a different approach. I can see he didn’t  get the -2 point bashing too. Trying to remove the no more question ban for the last month. Thank you very much for your helpful contribution !

Comment: (a) Please read my comment. Mavro _explained_ their answer; you dumped some code here without any context. Again, please read [answer]. (b) You didn't _just_ dump code here without any context; you did it _twice on the same question!_ (c) Your answer came up on the "low quality posts" review queue, probably because of the stuff I've already said. This draws attention to your answer. Maybe Mavro's answer isn't in that queue.

Comment: I modified my answer as per your request